# I want caption for image without hperlink underscore in horizontal view

Tags: html

[image]

```
<center><figure>
 <a href="doctor.html"><img class="img-circle" src="doctor.png" height="70" width="70" hspace="30"/><figcaption>Doctors</figcaption></a>
 <a href="lab.html"><img class="img-circle" src="lab.jpg" height="70" width="70" hspace="30"/><figcaption>Labs</figcaption></a>
 <a href="spa.html"><img class="img-circle" src="spa.png" height="70" width="70" hspace="30"/><figcaption>Spa</figcaption></a>
 <a href="gym.html"><img class="img-circle" src="gym.png"height="70" width="70" hspace="30"/><figcaption>Gym</figcaption></a>
</center></figure>
```

Comment: add `text-decoration:none` in css

Comment: i want image with caption in horizontal view.

Comment: try adding `style="float:left;"` to each `a` element

Comment: Yeah got but i want to place it in center exactly below search bar.

Comment: @JeevanRL You also have `</center></figure>` messed up. It should be `</figure></center>`

Comment: even though if i change </figure></center> its not aligned to center.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question but I think this is what you want.

I've used `display: inline-block;` so that each figure will display horizontally (of course if there is not enough space it will move to the next line).

I also moved your HTML around a little so each image has it's own figure.

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
figure a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" width="70" height="70">
      <figcaption>Doctors</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" width="70" height="70">
      <figcaption>Labs</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" width="70" height="70">
      <figcaption>Gym</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70" width="70" height="70">
      <figcaption>Spa</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</center>
```

Then of course you could start going a bit fancier, making it animated using css animations and using media queries

```css
figure.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px
}
figure.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
figure.menu figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  bottom: -30%;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
figure.menu:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  center {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 250px) {
  center {
    width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  figure.menu figcaption {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <figure class="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
      <figcaption>Doctors</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
      <figcaption>Labs</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
      <figcaption>Gym</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="menu">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
      <figcaption>Spa</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</center>
```

Mousing over one of the images/links will make the name slide in.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the underlines of a link, all you will need to do in your CSS file is:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none; // removes the underline for all links
  color: inherit; // removes the blue color and sets the parents color for all links

}
```

To get a image and text horizontally aligned with each other, what I would do at least would be to create a few lists that you align horizontally and add some style to:

```css
.horizontal-view ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.horizontal-view li {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-table;
}
.picture {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal-view">
  <li>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/70x70" class="picture" />
  </li>
  <li>My First Image Caption</li>
</ul>

<ul class="horizontal-view">
  <li>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/70x70" class="picture" />
  </li>
  <li>My Second Image Caption</li>
</ul>

<ul class="horizontal-view">
  <li>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/70x70" class="picture" />
  </li>
  <li>My Third Image Caption</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanx i fixed it.But i want to place image with caption in horizontal view. How can i do this one can you please help me out?

Comment: @JeevanRL Please see the edit coming up in just a moment!